# Example of two closed vector subspaces of $l^{2}$ whose sum is not closed

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

A problem asked me to show that $l^{2}$ is normed space with norm

$$\lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert = \sqrt{\sum^{ \infty }_{ \iota = 1} x^{2}_\iota}.$$

I've shown that this is indeed a norm where the triangle inequality relies on Cauchy-Schwarz.

I am however stuck on the follow up question:

Give an example of two closed linear subspace $A, B$ of $l^{2}$ such that the sum $A + B = \{ a + b: a \in A \quad \land \quad b \in B \}$ is not closed.

Question about latex. While typing in the problem I noticed that typing { and } in math mode does not work using \ { and \ }. How do I type sets on math.stackexchange?

Also I wasn't able to type in $\iota$ as an index on $x_{\iota}$ in the sum above.

Comment: I've edited the iota in the subindex with no issue. Not sure what the problem with curly braces is.

Comment: @MartinArgerami odd. I looked at your edit and I tried the same and it did not work for me. Perhaps my browser is having some issues. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: \wedge inserts the 'and' operator (if that is what you're asking, I can't quite tell)

Comment: @TyJensen When I was typing in the question I was trying to use set notation, i.e. the curly braces to enclose the set. When I was using \ {, the curly braces would just disappear. And the $\iota$ as a subscript on $x_{\iota}$ in the sum would just print the latex code as plain text. Perhaps this issue was only in the preview before posting the question. It seems to not occur after posting.

Comment: Strange, I assume it’s just your browser then.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate.